# Cannot invoke "java.util.Date.getTime()" because "this.openedTime" is null

Tags: websocket, serenity-bdd, java-websocket

I am using Serenity BDD framework java(maven) here we are trying to establish handshake connection but this error makes it difficult
i have this method

```
@Override
    public void onOpen(ServerHandshake handshakedata) {
        openedTime=new Date();
        System.out.print("Opened Connection "+dataContext.URI );
    }
```

an message which will ensure that handshake is done (i haven't added the message yet but thats the last desired output)

Comment: Don't see any Serenity-BDD related code here. And pls provide more info or reproducible example if you want anybody help.